# Rotate multiple selected metaballs

Tags: modeling

I want to select and rotate multiple metaballs (ie. an arm) but without success. Instead the individual objects happens to rotate around their corresponding centerpoints.

[image: Viewport screendump, rotate multiple metaballs]

Even parenting wont do.

Have I missed something?

Translating multiple metaballs, though, (grabbing to move) works fine and expected.

Comment: Have you checked what is the pivot point? Is it set to 'individual origins'?

Comment: Ahem ... having frantically clicked "manipulate centerpoint" [alt-,] on and off I thought I'd checked this also. Everything else than "individual origins" does the trick! Thanks for your kind help :-)